# Does clang capture ARC modifiers with __typeof?

Tags: objective-c, automatic-ref-counting, objective-c-blocks

It is known that a `block` may induce a retain cycle if the `block` implicitly retains an object that also retains the `block`. Example:

```
self.block = ^{
  [self foo];
};
```

A commonly prescribed workaround is to simply use a `__weak` `self` to avoid the retain cycle:

```
__typeof(self) __weak weakSelf = self;
self.block = ^{
  [weakSelf foo];
};
```

However, this can cause problems if `self` is dealloced in the middle of executing `foo`. A better strategy is to capture a `__strong` reference to the `__weak` `self` locally within the block.  However, I don't know whether the `__weak` modifier is captured `__typeof`, and if it is, can I override it with another `__strong`?

So, one of these, is correct, but which?

**A**

```
__typeof(self) __weak weakSelf = self;
self.block = ^{
  __typeof(self) strongWeakSelf = weakSelf;
  [strongWeakSelf foo];
};
```

**B**

```
__typeof(self) __weak weakSelf = self;
self.block = ^{
  __typeof(self) __strong strongWeakSelf = weakSelf;
  [strongWeakSelf foo];
};
```

**C**

```
__typeof(self) __weak weakSelf = self;
self.block = ^{
  __typeof(weakSelf) strongWeakSelf = weakSelf;
  [strongWeakSelf foo];
};
```

**D**

```
__typeof(self) __weak weakSelf = self;
self.block = ^{
  __typeof(weakSelf) __strong strongWeakSelf = weakSelf;
  [strongWeakSelf foo];
};
```

I hope that **C** is correct because it doesn't place `self` inside the `block` at all, and doesn't require an additional `__strong`.

**EDIT**

I totally screwed up my initial question and had my examples wrong. Inside my blocks, all my answers used to be `[weakSelf foo]` instead of `[strongWeakSelf foo]`.

Comment: they have no difference to me and I am using A.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**C** is (almost) what you want:

```
__typeof(self) __weak weakSelf = self;
self.block = ^{
  __typeof(weakSelf) strongWeakSelf = weakSelf;
  [strongWeakSelf foo]; //use strongWeakSelf, not weakSelf.
};
```

The `__strong` or `__weak` **ownership qualifier**  is different from the **type** that you get from `__typeof__()`.

**B** is the same as **A**, and **C** is the same as **D** because [local variables are implicitly `__strong`](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#arc-ownership-inference-variables).

But pedantically all these examples might not do what you want! Since `strongWeakSelf` isn't actually used the optimizer may be able to remove it.

Also, if you're testing any of these, be aware that the `objc_loadWeak` runtime function currently used to read `weakSelf` is (currently) doing a retain+autorelease of the value it loads today. So in practice, each of those examples is equally theadsafe. This isn't guaranteed to always be the case in the future, however.

Comment: Specifically, a Sufficiently Smart Compiler® could in the future use objc_loadWeakRetained + objc_release instead of objc_loadWeak

Comment: and A and B are the same as C and D because `__typeof(self)` and `__typeof(weakSelf)` are the same

Comment: Shit. I meant to reference strongWeakSelf everywhere. I screwed up my question so hard.

Comment: Yeah, I've been wondering about this too. The thing is, will typeof(self) inside a block capture the reference to self? Which in turn would create a retain cycle.

Comment: I just discovered `-Warc-repeated-use-of-weak`, and when I turn it on, it warns me about C. If I use D, the warnings go away.

Comment: typeof is purely compile time, like sizeof. It doesn't evaluate the argument. For example, if self is an NSString*, then writing typeof (self) is exactly the same as writing NSString*.

Comment: Where I can find that typeof is purely compile time? I'm having trouble finding confirmation of that.